# Do I understand these expressions correctly (Kalman filter)?

Tags: notation, kalman-filter

I'm reading a really nice discussion of Kalman filters [An Introduction to the Kalman Filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf) G. Welch, G. Bishop (SIGGRAPH Course 8, 2001) and as I usually do I'm trying to understand the math by "reading around" some of the notation I don't understand or remember, or just "getting it" from context. This usually works for me well enough but this time I'd really like to make sure since I'm going to implement a Kalman filter from scratch by reading about it here and then doing it.

I'm going to reproduce a small section here then ask my question(s):

> **4.1 The Discrete Kalman Filter**
>
> This section describes the filter in its original formulation (Kalman 1960) where the measurements occur and the state is estimated at discrete points in time.
>
> **4.1.1 The Process to be Estimated**
>
> The Kalman filter addresses the general problem of trying to estimate the state $x \in \Re^n$ of a discrete-time controlled process that is governed by the linear stochastic difference equation
>
> $$x_k = Ax_{k-1}+Bu_k+w_{k-1},$$
>
> with a measurement $z \in \Re^m$ that is
>
> $$z_k=H x_k + v_k.$$
>
> The random variables $w_k$ and $v_k$ represent the process and measurement noise (respectively). They are assumed to be independent (of each other), white, and with normal probability distributions
>
> $$p(w) \sim N(0, Q),$$
>    $$p(v) \sim N(0,R).$$
>
> In practice, the *process noise covariance Q* and *measurement noise covariance R* matrices might change with each time step or measurement, however here we assume they are constant.

**Q1:** Does $x \in \Re^n$ mean for my practical purposes that $x$ represent an array of real numbers with length $n$? I know the notation is from set theory, but for scripting purposes, would $\Re^n$ suggest 1D array of floats of length $n$?

**Q2:** Does $p(v) \sim N(0, R)$ mean that the probability distribution of possible values of $w$ is a normal distribution (thus the "$N$") with a centroid at zero and a standard deviation of $Q$? Why the use of "$\sim$" instead of "$=$"? Is $N$ not normalized?

Comment: Q1: YES. $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$.

Comment: Q2: it seems the "standard" [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Notation).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is the $\sim$ standard also? Any chance $R$ is variance, or $\sigma^2$ rather than $\sigma$? Maybe it's not me, just ambiguous?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution might be helpful.

Comment: @MikeMathMan indeed it might, thanks! It looks like $R$ here is $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ there, and in the simplest one-dimensional case would be like the standard deviation $\sigma$ squared? That would leave me with only the $\sim$ notation instead of $=$ to figure out, used both there and here. I don't know even know what to call that symbol. I'd venture 'tilde' or 'approximately' but that's just a guess.

Comment: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tilde.html  4. for tilde use in statistics.

Comment: @MikeMathMan again thank you! I'm off in search of somebody named Markov who I'm told is being hidden. In any event, to avoid the possibility of link "evolution" (rot); *4. In statistics, the tilde is frequently used to mean "has the distribution (of)," for instance, X∼N(0,1) means "the stochastic (random) variable X has the distribution N(0,1) (the standard normal distribution). If X and Y are stochastic variables then X∼Y means "X has the same distribution as Y.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll re-post the answer as an answer, since SE comments can be considered ephemeral.

> **Q1:** Does $x \in \Re^n$ mean for my practical purposes that $x$ represent an array of real numbers with length $n$? I know the notation is from set theory, but for scripting purposes, would $\Re^n$ suggest 1D array of floats of length $n$?

YES, per [@MauroALLEGRANZA's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344973/#comment4828623_2344973).

> **Q2:** Does $p(v) \sim N(0, R)$ mean that the probability distribution of possible values of $w$ is a normal distribution (thus the "$N$") with a centroid at zero and a standard deviation of $Q$? Why the use of "$\sim$" instead of "$=$"? Is $N$ not normalized?

Here $N$ is a [Multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) per [@MikeMathMan's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344973/#comment4828702_2344973), what I would loosely call an $n$-*dimensional Gaussian* with $R$ being an array of $\sigma^2$ values, the squares of the standard deviations.

Per [@MikeMathMan's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344973/#comment4828848_2344973) the tilde "$\sim$" used as its own symbol (rather than on top of something else) is described in the [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/) article on [Tilde](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tilde.html), where item #4 applies here:

> The tilde is sometimes used as its own symbol.
>
> 1. In asymptotic notation, f∼phi is used to mean that f/phi->1.
> 2. Physicists and astronomers use same notation to mean "f is of the same order of magnitude as phi."
> 3. In set theory, x∼y means that there is an equivalence relation between x and y.
> 4. **In statistics, the tilde is frequently used to mean "has the distribution (of)**," for instance, X∼N(0,1) means "the stochastic (random) variable X has the distribution N(0,1) (the standard normal distribution). If X and Y are stochastic variables then X∼Y means "X has the same distribution as Y.